# Should I use regexp on frontend or backend side to create a custom elastic search body query?

Tags: javascript, regex, elasticsearch, optimization, request

I am currently developing a syntactic search engine to detect a query in a string entered by a user. I will use RegExp to detect logical operators like 'And' and 'Or'. Then I will detect each term of the query entered and build the body of an elastic search query from this string.

I would like to know what is the most optimized way to do this: is it better to call RegExp on the frontend and then send an already built query to the backend in this style:

```
body: {
      query: 
        buildQueryAnd(
          { match: { some_field: "someData" } },
          { range: { "@timestamp": { "gte": addMinutes(new Date(), -600000), "lt": new Date(), format: "strict_date_optional_time" } } },
        ),
      _source: buildSource("someField1","someField2",...),
      sort: [
        {
          "@timestamp": {
            order: "desc"
          }
        }
      ], 
      size: 50
    }
```

Or is it better to send the raw user input from the frontend to the backend and do the operator and term lookup to build the query on the backend side?

Comment: why can't you directly use the query string (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) which supports these operator Out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I may have misunderstood something, but from what I understand, elastic's query string API allows you to request data directly from elastic, but if I want to set up a grammar specific to my organization, I'll have to set up a custom syntax search system. Then, once I have decoded the user's request I can use any of elastic's APIs to request my data. Or is there a way to interpret a complex string with this API like: "some_field1 whitout some_subfield2 and some_field3 with some_subfield3 or some_subfield4" which would then create my query object in the right form?

Comment: I'm pointing out that I don't want the end user to use special characters, they should be able to provide terms with simple operators that are then interpreted and perhaps passed in a more elastic-like syntax.

Comment: So basically you need to use the `regexp` either on Front-end or back-end to create the Elasticsearch queries according to your requirement, you just want to know which place is better to do it, ie Front-end or Back-end correct ?

Comment: Yes that's right, my question is more about a design choice. Now that you point it out I may not have posted in the right forum, should I move my topic to stack exchange: software engineering?

Comment: yes its a design question, but IMHO folks would suggest do it in BE, as regexp might take a long time and doing it in Front-end will increase the page-load time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245754/discussion-between-amit-and-vincent).